# Accessing an array within a struct causes warnings with clang

Tags: c++, temporary-objects

```
struct test{
   char c_arr[1];
};

test array[1] = {{1}};

test get(int index){
 return array[index];
}

int main(){
  char* a =  get(0).c_arr;
  return 0;
}
```

Compiling this with `g++` has no warnings but with `clang++` prints the following:

```
warning: temporary whose address is used as value of local variable 'a' will be destroyed at the end of the full-expression
```

Is this incorrect? does `get(0).c_arr` not return a pointer to a global array?

or does `get(0)` return a temporary variable and the compiler thinks `c_arr` is just an instance of it, and not global, by mistake?

### Edit

Why passing this temp variable to a function works without warnings?

```
void call(char* in){}

int main(){
  call(get(0).c_arr);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`get` returns by-value, then `get(0)` does return a temporary which gets destroyed after the full expression, left `a` being a dangling pointer.

Note that the returned temporary `test` is copied from `array[index]`, including the array data member `c_arr`. `a` is supposed to point to the 1st element of the data member array `c_arr` of the temporary `test`, after the full expression (i.e. the `;` in `char* a =  get(0).c_arr;`) the whole temporary `test` (and its data member `c_arr`) is destroyed, then `a` becomes dangling.

If `get` returns by-reference then it'll be fine.

```
test& get(int index){
 return array[index];
}
```

**EDIT**

The code you added is fine. The temporary is destroyed after the full expression, i.e. after `;` in `call(get(0).c_arr);`. The pointer passed to `call` remains valid inside `call`.

Comment: here end of the expression means end of `get(0).c_arr`? but `c_arr` here is returning a global pointer, which will remain valid?

Comment: @Dan No, `get` returns a `test` copied from `array[index]`, not the element of the global array directly.

Comment: i see so `get(0).c_arr` returns a pointer to an array which doesn't exist anymore, not the global array. Why wouldn't `g++` warn of it tho? even `clang` when compiling `C` is ok with it? How can this be fixed in C if I may ask?

Comment: I also added an extra question under `edit`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the information. Can I also bug you on why this woks in `C` without warnings, is it undefined behaviour? what would be a workaround as references don't exist?

Comment: @Dan I think it depends on compilers to issue a diagnostic or not. You're not using the dangling pointer. BTW dereference on it leads to UB.

Comment: @Dan Answer revised for *edit*. And sorry I'm not familiar with C, not sure it's UB or not in C.

Comment: Not a problem, I will ask a new question specific to C on this.